# Protractor - button click calls the callback sooner than desired

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I have a protractor test for login page, that submits creds and checks if index page is loaded. I am passing a callback function to the button click's `then` function, assuming the callback will be invoked after the promise returned by `click` function is resolved.

```
var protractor = require('protractor')
describe('E2E: main page', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    browser.get('http://localhost:8001/login.html/');
  });
  it("login in the portal", function(){
    var d = protractor.promise.defer();
    element(by.model('loginParams.email')).sendKeys('saravana0209@r.com');
    element(by.model('loginParams.password')).sendKeys('password');
    element(by.name('normalLogin')).click().then(function(){
        //it crashes here before selecting the sub menu item
        element(by.xpath('//a[@title="subMenuItem"]')).click()
        console.log("sub-menu item has been chosen in the ribbon")
        setTimeout(function() { d.fulfill('ok')}, 50000)
    })
    expect(d).toBe('ok');
  })
});
```

But the callback is getting invoked, when the page loading is in progress and it crashes the test, since the element with `title`, `subMenuItem` is still not loaded.
Error is,

```
Error: Failed: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[@title="Venues"] because of the following error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'createNSResolver' on 'Document': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can *wait for submenu to be visible* before making a click:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

element(by.name('normalLogin')).click().then(function() {
    var subMenu = element(by.xpath('//a[@title="subMenuItem"]'));

    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(subMenu), 5000);
    subMenu.click();

    console.log("sub-menu item has been chosen in the ribbon");
    setTimeout(function() { d.fulfill('ok')}, 50000);
});
```

---

Since, it looks like all of the problems are coming from the *manual angular bootstraping*, you would [have to use `browser.driver.get()`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/6ebc4c3f8b557a56e53e0a1622d1b44b59f5bc04/docs/system-setup.md#setting-up-the-system-under-test):

> If your page does manual bootstrap Protractor will not be able to load
>   your page using browser.get. Instead, use the base webdriver instance
>   - browser.driver.get. This means that Protractor does not know when your page is fully loaded, and you may need to add a wait statement to
>   make sure your tests avoid race conditions.

Which could lead to something like:

```
element(by.name('normalLogin')).click(); 
browser.sleep(3000); 
browser.driver.get("index.html");
```

Login, let it log you in by having a delay (sleep is bad, yeah) and manually get the index page after.

---

You can also work with a disabled synchronization between protractor and angular by setting the `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;`, but this have a lot of drawbacks - you would have to start using Explicit Waits (`browser.wait()`) a lot. You can though try to play around with this flag and set it temporarily to `true` before loading a page and set back to `false` after.

Comment: it didn't help... it crashes with same error... as i said, the new page - index.html is a newer angular application and i am not sure, if protractor is doing load synchronization after the button click... and i increased the second param to `browser.param` but of no use...

Comment: @MadhavanKumar thanks for trying out! Which protractor and angular versions are used?

Comment: i tried out another version of browser.wait, with no progress... see the issue @https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2358... protractor is versioned 1.8.0 and angular is versioned 1.2.16....

Comment: @MadhavanKumar good, first thing to try could be to update to the latest protractor (2.1 currently)

Comment: @MadhavanKumar could you also note where the `ng-app` are defined in `login.html` and `index.html`?

Comment: there is no `ng-app` defined here.. the team has a lot of js files and so, it is using requireJs. For some reasons, the team has decided that `ng-app` does not work well with requireJs and they are bootstrapping using `angular.bootstrap(document,[...])`

Comment: moving to 2.1 from 1.8 didn't solve any problem, except that it made it impossible to use firefox with directConnect set as True -- https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2134.. but that is okay, alecxe

Comment: @MadhavanKumar yeah, I think this manual bootstrap is the culprit here. From [system-setup docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/6ebc4c3f8b557a56e53e0a1622d1b44b59f5bc04/docs/system-setup.md#setting-up-the-system-under-test): *If your page does manual bootstrap Protractor will not be able to load your page using browser.get. Instead, use the base webdriver instance - browser.driver.get.*

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?:

```
 element(by.name('normalLogin')).click()
    browser.wait(function() {
      return browser.driver.isElementPresent(by.xpath('//a[@title="Venues"]'))
    }).then(function(){
         var venueLink = by.xpath('//a[@title="Venues"]')
         browser.driver.isElementPresent(venueLink).then(function(){
           console.log("tenant login process successful")
           element(venueLink).click()
        })
    });
```

Protractor works asynchronously, so

```
var venueLink = by.xpath('//a[@title="Venues"]')
```

will be executed while

```
browser.wait(function() {
      return browser.driver.isElementPresent(by.xpath('//a[@title="Venues"]'))
    })
```