# protractor error: document unloaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Have something like

```
let a = element(by.css('.some-class'));
console.log(a.getText());
```

result:

> Message:
>       Failed: javascript error: document unloaded while waiting for result
>         (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.86)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498513 (2c63aa53b2c658de596ed550eb5267ec5967b351),platform=Linux
>   4.4.0-93-generic x86_64)   Stack:
>       JavascriptError: javascript error: document unloaded while waiting for result

so when i use something like:

```
element.all().then()
```

or

```
element().getText().then()
```

i have the same output. What's wrong?

And if i dont write `browser.waitForAngular();` in start of all `it()` callbacks tests passig by random. But if i put it in `beforeEach()` it does not change anything.

Comment: Is the document loaded at the time you search for the element?

Comment: protractor is waiting for loading, isnt it?

Oh.. No. If i put browser.sleep before it works, but it is not what i want. :(

Comment: Seems that you need to specify a full loaded event, see this answer, maybe you can find any help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31498207/protractor-button-click-calls-the-callback-sooner-than-desired

Comment: add something like browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element), 10000), but 1 of ~3 times have same result for one of cases :(